# Pandas pivot table with multiple aggfunc using user function

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

i had a dataframe contains the columns ['ssanames','tech','duration','count','perc']

[image]

i want to create a pivot table with multiple aggfunc and one of the column is a userfunction and tired this for

```
func = lambda x: 100-(x['duraiton']*100/(24*60*31*x['count']))
# tech_ssawise_duration_btscount['perc'] = tech_ssawise_duration_btscount.apply(lambda x: 100 - (100 * x['duration']/(x['count']*24*no_of_days*60)), axis=1).round(2)
tech_ssawise_duration_btscount.pivot_table(index='ssaname', columns='tech',
           values=['duration','count','perc'], 
           margins=True, aggfunc={'count':np.sum,
                                 'duration':np.sum,
                                 'perc': func}, fill_value=0).to_excel(tech_availability)
```

The output should be

[image]

Comment: [Stack Overflow Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).  It is likely the question will be down-voted.  You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible.

Comment: Your `func` is not an aggreation function. That is, it returns a series with the same length with the original dataframe. Unless the combination `ssaname` and `tech` are unique, you can't pivot :-).